# Looping through rows is slowing my google appscript down. How can I speed it up?

Tags: performance, optimization, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 40 Google sheet files i need to change the title colors on. They are in varying rows on the columns 1 and 13. I need to find where they are, and change their colors.

This works, painfully slowly. Is there anyway i can write this more efficiently? I feel like looping through the rows up to 57 (which i know to be the last row possible for a title) is slowing down my process, but i can't think of any better way.

```
    function colorchange() {
    // The following defines the variable SpreadsheetIDs, which is a list of all the ID's that are going to be changed
      var spreadsheetIDs = ["1TZK5s3KvAFn9AMgWjIyPFAkjvhwL-3sGy5ieipQV-R8", //template
                    "1NSctLmGT0eWzvSj7P_NOUmgR79nIIokEEiaTJo6_Bb8", //1
                    "1plfjNQx4aFFnwcqMfv_wohbiYnlC_NVjW-etBM-xm5c", //2
                    "1i7myzXNFiFM6ZtkG590Hg4oEr-cAV8gsWxlV7rjL2b8", //3
                    "1-3r7D6nsVLT1FEZhGpGP9eF9G9HUZmuEe22aDajNBA0", //4
                    "1LBob3F3D1E__K6CJyBBIssho_cLkxm9uD00DP03QQz8", //5
                    "1Bot9TAbAr-g_Dgbqi4WJvXfE-Gt9t2ErxJk3Y-pvWZs", //6
                    "18kOx3-Q0DQhAA7jm19UZQhBUYShYVORWlQIgU_iicq4", //7
                    "1aHZ3FHUW6jt5HpuYb0fpBvfgTqSazXzZwJbvQEa8Qcs", //8
                    "1WkDHWL6sIkSu9qt_nizzXm2er-hxzuXEf8GsCTq3fug", //9
                    "1ZLDjW3VTMaumQIbihvyELyCuBghcn_GrQmuzCPnno9Y", //10
                   //ECT until 40ish spreadsheetID's
                   ];
      var i=0,color="",sheet,thisID="",e=1,c=1;

    // This calls the Browser input box and defines it the color Variable
        color = Browser.inputBox("Enter the color");

      for (i=0;i<spreadsheetIDs.length;++i) {
        thisID=spreadsheetIDs[i];
    //This opens the first ID, and opens up the Sheet1 sheet. ALL of the sheets in the territory MUST have this name.
        sheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById(thisID).getSheetByName('Sheet1');

    //This loops through the column 1 and 13 and checks for the correct font size all the way up to row 59.
    //When it finds the correct fontsize, it sets the fontcolor to the color variable value.
    for (e=1;e<58;++e) {
      //Row A
         c=1
          if(sheet.getRange(e,c).getFontSize() == '24') {
              sheet.getRange(e,c).setFontColor(color);}
      //Row M
         c=13
          if(sheet.getRange(e,c).getFontSize() == '24') {
              sheet.getRange(e,c).setFontColor(color);}
          }
    //Set Background for A1 and Color for D1
    sheet.getRange(1,1).setBackground(color);
    sheet.getRange(1,4).setFontColor(color);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this [Best Practices for App Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) can help you.

**Use batch operations**

> You can write scripts to take maximum advantage of the built-in
>   caching, by minimizing the number of reads and writes. Alternating
>   read and write commands is slow. To speed up a script, read all data
>   into an array with one command, perform any operations on the data in
>   the array, and write the data out with one command.
>
> Here's an example — an example you should not follow or use. The
>   Spreadsheet Fractal Art script in the Gallery (only available in the
>   older version of Google Sheets) uses the following code to set the
>   background colors of every cell in a 100 x 100 spreadsheet grid:

```
// DO NOT USE THIS CODE. It is an example of SLOW, INEFFICIENT code.
// FOR DEMONSTRATION ONLY
var cell = sheet.getRange('a1');
for (var y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
  xcoord = xmin;
  for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    var c = getColor_(xcoord, ycoord);
    cell.offset(y, x).setBackgroundColor(c);
    xcoord += xincrement;
  }
  ycoord -= yincrement;
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

> The script is inefficient: it loops through 100 rows and 100 columns,
>   writing consecutively to 10,000 cells. The Google Apps Script
>   write-back cache helps, because it forces a write-back using flush at
>   the end of every line. Because of the caching, there are only 100
>   calls to the Spreadsheet.
>
> But the code can be made much more efficient by batching the calls.
>   Here's a rewrite in which the cell range is read into an array called
>   colors, the color assignment operation is performed on the data in the
>   array, and the values in the array are written out to the spreadsheet:

```
// OKAY TO USE THIS EXAMPLE or code based on it.
var cell = sheet.getRange('a1');
var colors = new Array(100);
for (var y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
  xcoord = xmin;
  colors[y] = new Array(100);
  for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    colors[y][x] = getColor_(xcoord, ycoord);
    xcoord += xincrement;
  }
  ycoord -= yincrement;
}
sheet.getRange(1, 1, 100, 100).setBackgroundColors(colors);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed the slowest way to do it!

What you need to do is read all of the values into an array, change the values, and then write them back in one go.

So check out calls like getValues and getFontColors and setValues and setFontColors in the Range class which will allow you to only make two calls per sheet to the Range object and massively reduce your execution times.

Comment: After i've read the values into the array, how do i target said values to change the specific values I want? I need to change specifically the ones with the FontSize of X. So, after all these FontSizes are written back into my array, how do i know where they originated from to target them for a FontColor change?

Comment: I did it using 2 nested loops with an if statement in them checking the cell value. The cell value was taken using parseint (i dont know why it was in a string value) and then adding 1 to it. (Because the loops started at 0 and the google sheet started at 1.) Works perfectly!

Comment: Cool. Sorry for delay in replying. 

So I would read the sizes and values into two arrays for the whole range, using getFontSizes() and getValues() and then loop through that array using nested loops and change the corresponding value in the values array - make sense?

Sounds like that's what you did anyway!

Comment: Interesting, i actually didn't getValues(). I used the loop number of the nested loops to figure out where i was on the page. I wonder if this is faster or slower than getting the values and finding the cell that way.